# Change format of a date field in model if column contains null value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Added below data annotation attribute in model date property:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public string Upload_Date { get; set; }
```

But if this date field is having null value then model will not return data while executing procedure with the below line:

```
 IEnumerable<HistoryList> HistoryList = await _SQLHelper.GetRecordsAsync<HistoryList>("[dbo].[USP_LIST_HISTORY]", parameters);

public async Task<List<T>> GetRecordsAsync<T>(string spName, List<ParameterInfo> parameters)
{
    //...
    recordList = await Task.FromResult(SqlMapper.QueryAsync<T>(objConnection, spName, p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).Result.ToList());
    return recordList;
}
```

Getting this error after executing the line `recordList = await Task.FromResult(SqlMapper.QueryAsync<T>(objConnection, spName, p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).Result.ToList());`:

> String '' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

What can be done to change date format in such scenarios if date column contain null value?

Comment: Please provide the detailed in formation of your db and sql string ,I tried in my case,but it works well,couldn't reproduce the error

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.nulldisplaytext?view=net-7.0

try playing with the NullDisplayText property

```
[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true, NullDisplayText = "[Null]")]
```

Comment: tried above solution, still I'm getting same error.

Comment: Where, exactly, is the exception happening?  Can you run your stored procedure and get a look at the raw data?  Maybe there is where the issue is?  Is it returning the date in some format that is not able to convert to date?